# Tomcat / Gradle Spring Application - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, gradle, tomcat

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot Application on external Tomcat 8.5.73 but when i browse on my `localhost:8080/myApplicationName` i get *"The requested resource is not available"* error.

I have successfully deployed my Angular Front-End (on `localhost:8080/myAngularApp`) and it works fine.

These are the step that I've already followed:

- Set JRE_HOME (jre1.8.0_51) and CATALINA_HOME variables correctly;
- Set WAR packaging in Gradle;
- Added `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as provided in my Gradle dependencies;
- Extended my application with `SpringBootServletInitializer` and overrided the method `SpringApplicationBuilder configure`;
- Built app as `Gradle War`;
- Added the .war file in /webapps tomcat's folder.

When I launch `startup.bat` i get:

```
WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [5.0]. Default version will be used.
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [ .. \tomcat\webapps\myApplicationName.war] has finished in [4,823] ms
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 10657 ms
```

I've also tried to set `java` instead of `jvm` on startup and shutdown properties in tomcat8w but i get the same error.

I can see every deployed app on tomcat manager panel but it goes 404 every time except for my Frontend.

I have sent the .war to one of my colleagues and it works fine on his machine, so I am 99% sure that the problem is somewhere in my tomcat config. Anyway the only difference between me and my colleague is that he can see the "spring logo" and spring logs on his tomcat log when he starts tomcat via startup.bat.

Comment: And you left out **which version** of spring boot you are using. If you are using 3+ yo must use Tomcat 10.x, anything lower should work. Judging from the error you get you are using 3+. But why even deploy instead of using the embedded container. Finally `Built app as Gradle war`? What do you mean with that last part? Spring Boot should build the war through the proper plugin.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm using Spring 3.0.5. Yes i built the .war through the gradle plugin, and i need to deploy it on an external tomcat test server. So with Spring 3.x.x. I need Tomcat 10?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot (which uses Spring 6.0) 3.0. Yes minimum requirement is Java17 and Tomcat 10. Simply because Spring Boot 3.x is for JakartaEE and not JavaEE.